# SOLR Custom Index Causing Error

Tags: solr, indexing

I am converting a Lucene custom index to a SOLR custom index. I got the Cores working for the default indexes, but having trouble converting my custom indexes. I got through some of the issues, but the following error I am not sure what is causing it. Any ideas?

**Unable to process 'AddFieldByFieldName' config section**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
<contentSearch>
  <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="news_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>

        <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />

        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">

          <fieldMap             type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="headline"                storageType="YES"  indexType="TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
              </field>
            </fieldNames>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change this

```xml
<fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
  <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
    <field fieldName="headline" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
      <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    </field>
  </fieldNames>
```

to:

```xml
<fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
  <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
    <field fieldName="headline" returnType="string" />
  </fieldNames>
```

That should match the expected Solr config.